# Image processing : luminance weighted 2

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to weigh values of luminance on a new image.
I have an image (5px.jpg) of 5 pixels with these luminance :50,100,150,200,250.

I have a vector of coefficient.

I created a new `Mat Z` which combine luminance of 5px.jpg and the coefficient.

So, my first value of luminance is 50 (lum[0]=50) and I want it to be applied on the 5.1 (coef[0]=5.1) first pixel of my matrix. To do that, I need to weight the 6th pixel with the first and the second value of luminance. In my case,the luminance of my 6th pixel will be 95 because (0.1*50)+(0.9*100)=95

And so on...

But I do not know why my code does not works.

I had already asked a similar question for a vector [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695954/image-processing-luminance-weighted/34696513?noredirect=1#comment57143077_34696513) and now, I'm try to adapt to an image.

My picture in input :

[image]

My output :

[image]

```
#define MPI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
#define RAD2DEG (180./MPI)
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Mat image = imread("5px.jpg", 1);
    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout << "Couldn't load " << image << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Image upload, go" << endl;
    }


    namedWindow("ImageIn", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("ImageIn", image);
    Mat imgGrayScale;

    cvtColor(image, imgGrayScale, CV_BGR2GRAY);


    float *deltaP = new float[imgGrayScale.cols];
    float *angle = new float[imgGrayScale.cols];
    float *coeff = new float[imgGrayScale.cols];
    int col;


    for (col = 0; col < imgGrayScale.cols; ++col)
    {
        //cout << "position x = " << col << endl;
        deltaP[col] = imgGrayScale.at<uchar>(0, col);
        //cout << "luminance = " << deltaP[col] << endl;

        angle[col] = acos(deltaP[col] / 255);
        //cout << "angle =" << angle[col] << endl;

        coeff[col] = (1 / cos(angle[col]));
        cout << "coeff = " << coeff[col] << endl;
    }

    int width = imgGrayScale.size().width;
    int height = imgGrayScale.size().height;

    int width2 = width * 5;

    int idx_coef = 0;
    Mat Z = Mat::zeros(height, width2, CV_8UC1);


    //for (int r = 0; r < imgGrayScale.rows; r++)
    //{
    //cout << "Saut de ligne "  << endl << endl << endl;
    for (int t = 0; t < imgGrayScale.cols; t++)
    {
        //cout << "Saut de colonne "  << endl;
        // Attribue le coeff à une variable
        int c = int(coeff[idx_coef]);
        //cout << "x" << t << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        {
            Z.at<uchar>(0, c) = imgGrayScale.at<uchar>(0, t);
        }


        float alpha = fmod(coeff[idx_coef], 1.f);
        float beta = 1.f - alpha;

        Z.at<uchar>(0, c + 1) = (alpha * imgGrayScale.at<uchar>(0, t) + beta *  imgGrayScale.at<uchar>(0, t + 1));

        idx_coef++;
        coeff[idx_coef] = coeff[idx_coef] - beta;



        if (idx_coef >= width - 1)
        {

            int cc = int(coeff[idx_coef]);
            for (int i = 0; i < cc; ++i)
            {
                Z.at<uchar>(0, c) = imgGrayScale.at<uchar>(0, t);
            }
            idx_coef = 0;
            break;

        }

    }
    //}

    namedWindow("m", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("m", Z);
    imwrite("lumianacetest.jpg", Z);
    int t = waitKey();
    if ((char)t == 27)

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference with your previous question? Also, saving values as jpeg is a **bad** idea, since the jpeg quantization will alter the values. You better use FileStorage in this case.

Comment: There is no difference, but my Mat Z have not the luminance than I want. I think there is a problem with fmod function.

Comment: Please post your 5px image, I'll give this a look

Comment: It is too small, It had just 5 pixels. I created on Photoshop a [5x1] image than i filled with these values 50,100,150,200,250.

Comment: Ok. however, reopen it with photoshop. Most likely the values are changed :D

Comment: No there are not modified

Comment: you messed up with indices. Why didn't you keep the code that works on a vector and then copy into a Mat?

Comment: Because I dont know how to do that because vector have one dimension and my program will work on images, so matrix.

Comment: Ok, but here your Z matrix has only 1 dimension...

Comment: yes, it's just for test, if you see in comment I prepared the pass line on an image.

Imagine my coefficient vector does not change. I will apply these changes , columns by columns and row by row

Comment: ok, got it.... let me see.. you seems just to have messed up with indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You messed up with the indices while accessing the matrix `Z`. You shoudn't access `Z` at column `c`, but you need access the *current* column (as a `vector::push_back` would do). So you can keep the current index column in a variable, here `idx_z`, and increment it every time you access `Z`
- Here your `Z` is `CV_8U`, so you lose accuracy since your values are `float`. You can create `Z` as `CV_32F`, and if you need to store values in `CV_8U` format to save the image, you can convert to `CV_8U` later, eventually.
- The last columns of `Z` won't be set to any value (so I initialized them with value `0`). If you need them to have the last value as in the `imgGrayScale`, just decomment the relevant part of the code.

Here the code:

```
#define MPI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
#define RAD2DEG (180./MPI)

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat1b imgGrayScale = (Mat1b(2, 5) <<    50, 100, 150, 200, 250,
                                            50, 100, 150, 200, 250);

    vector<float> deltaP(imgGrayScale.cols);
    vector<float> angle(imgGrayScale.cols);
    vector<float> coeff(imgGrayScale.cols);
    int col;


    for (col = 0; col < imgGrayScale.cols; ++col)
    {
        //cout << "position x = " << col << endl;
        deltaP[col] = imgGrayScale.at<uchar>(0, col);
        //cout << "luminance = " << deltaP[col] << endl;

        angle[col] = acos(deltaP[col] / 255);
        //cout << "angle =" << angle[col] << endl;

        coeff[col] = (1 / cos(angle[col]));
        cout << "coeff = " << coeff[col] << endl;
    }

    int width = imgGrayScale.size().width;
    int height = imgGrayScale.size().height;

    int width2 = width * 5;


    Mat1f Z(height, width2, 0.f);


    for (int r = 0; r < imgGrayScale.rows; r++)
    {
        int idx_lum = 0;
        int idx_coef = 0;
        int idx_z = 0;

        vector<float> coef = coeff;

        // Set all values in Z to the last value in imgGrayScale
        Z.row(r) = imgGrayScale(r, imgGrayScale.cols-1);

        while (true)
        {
            int c = int(coef[idx_coef]);

            for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
            {
                Z(r, idx_z++) = imgGrayScale(r, idx_lum);
            }


            float alpha = fmod(coef[idx_coef], 1.f);
            float beta = 1.f - alpha;

            Z(r, idx_z++) = (alpha * imgGrayScale(r, idx_lum) + beta *  imgGrayScale(r, idx_lum + 1));

            idx_coef++;
            idx_lum++;
            coef[idx_coef] = coef[idx_coef] - beta;

            if (idx_lum >= imgGrayScale.cols - 1 || idx_coef >= coef.size() - 1)
            {

                int cc = int(coef[idx_coef]);
                for (int i = 0; i < cc; ++i)
                {
                    Z(r, idx_z++) = imgGrayScale(r, idx_lum);
                }
                idx_coef = 0;
                break;

            }

        }
    }

    Mat1b ZZ;
    Z.convertTo(ZZ, CV_8U);

    cout << "Float values:" << endl;
    cout << Z << endl << endl;

    cout << "Uchar values:" << endl;
    cout << ZZ << endl << endl;

    namedWindow("m", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("m", Z);
    imwrite("lumianacetest.png", ZZ);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes but when I import luminancetest.jpg in Photoshop, the values are : 


69,69,69,69,69,118,123,140,198,227,251,252,250,251,251,251,251...


or I would like 50,50,50,50,50,95,100,117,182,218,255,255...


As my previous post. I'm lost..

Comment: Check now! 1) save in png to avoid compression (yes, some values are modified by jpeg compression), 2) You can see on stdout that values are correct.

Comment: Weird, png file does not work also. I'm agree the values in terminal are good but, on Photoshop, same problem :/

Comment: Probably Photoshop doesn't load the image correctly, i.e. applies some color space transformation / gamma correction / whatever. However, you don't need Photoshop in the first place :D. I can see correct values with paint.net

Comment: Yes maybe color space. It will be good if it show me good values because this program is for correct loss light on image scanned. Anyway, how to remplace your Mat1b by a real image ?

Comment: `Mat1b imgGrayScale = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

Comment: However, if your matrix represent generica values, and not pixel intensities, it's usually better to use `FileStorage`

Comment: Ok ! Thanks for information. I have inported lumiancetest.png in GIMP, it is ok. Photoshop..hum ;)

Comment: Well, problem solved :D Please remember to upvote / mark as answer then.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! With Miki, keep calm and go to Italy ;)